# Strange behavior when including <vector>

Tags: c++, stdvector

I see some very strange behavior when I include the standard vector library. Can anyone tell me what is causing these failures? Whose toes am I stepping on and is there a general case of this bug that I should watch out for?

I'm using the [ROOT](http://root.cern.ch/drupal/) C++ interpreter. From either the command line interpreter interface or from compiled code,

```
$ root -l
root [0] #include <vector>
root [1] float max = -1.15;
root [2] if (max < -1 && max > -1.2) max = 2;
Error: Variable name has bad character 'max<-1&&max>-1207' (tmpfile):1:
Error: Symbol max<-1&&max>-1207 is not defined in current scope  (tmpfile):1:
Error: Variable name has bad character 'max<-1&&max>-1' (tmpfile):1:
Error: Symbol max is not defined in current scope  (tmpfile):1:
Error: non class,struct,union object $max<-1&&max>-1 used with . or -> (tmpfile):1:
*** Interpreter error recovered ***
root [3] max
(float)(-1.14999997615814209e+00)
```

Then if I add some parentheses that should do nothing:

```
root [4] if ((max < -1) && (max > -1.2)) max = 2; 
root [5] max
(float)2.00000000000000000e+00
root [6] .qqqqqqqqqqqq
```

If I just quit root normally, root seg-faults. If I don't include  it works as it should:

```
[abarker@cmslpc29 macro]$ r
root [0] float max = -1.15;
root [1] if (max < -1 && max > -1.2) max = 2;
root [2] max
(float)2.00000000000000000e+00
```

Also, if I change the variable name to something other than "max" the problem vanishes.

Comment: Show us the code that generates the output.

Comment: You're looking at all of it.

Comment: Oh, okay, sorry! I'm not familiar with root and it looked like the actual code was missing.

Comment: Not sure why (haven't used ROOT), but it appears to be interpreting "max < -1 && max >" as a single expression. Is max possibly a keyword in ROOT, or is it being defined by som implicitly-included header?

Comment: From: http://root.cern.ch/viewvc/branches/v5-34-00-patches/cint/doc/limitati.txt it looks like the authors of the interpreter suggest avoiding using the STL for interpreted programs

Comment: I was going to give a longer answer but it's entirely speculation. ..ROOT has a bug (it should not segfault on code it interprets), max is a function or macro, the extra parenthesis introduces some special kind of scope or all of the above. Or we've entered the Twilight Zone and we're all screwed.

Comment: JustSid: no worries. 
Well, max isn't a keyword in root and it's not defined by default in a blank environment. So it does not seem to be in any implicit headers.

Comment: Maybe it's getting confused with `std::max` (which could be getting pulled in with vector) and trying to treat it as a template?

Comment: Fred, I think you hit it. 
If I just include <vector> and probe max, I see that max is a const void* with some address and max(int i, int j) becomes defined. So even though these are not functions listed in vector's documentation they're getting stepped on and it tires to compare numbers to a pointer to a function.

Answer (score 1):

max is being quietly defined by < vector >.

```
$ root -l
root [0] max
Error: Symbol max is not defined in current scope  (tmpfile):1:
*** Interpreter error recovered ***
root [1] max(1,2)
Error: Function max(1,2) is not defined in current scope  (tmpfile):1:
*** Interpreter error recovered ***
root [2] #include <vector>
root [3] max
(const void*)0x2b6758507c37
root [4] max(2,3)
(const int)3
```

So some bug in the interpreter is tripping over the overloaded name and messing up the scope rules.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the interpreter is seeing `max` as `std::max`, which is a template. That's why it's trying to treat the text inside `<` and `>` as a template argument. This is **highly** non-conforming; `max` is defined in the namespace `std`, so does **not** clash with the variable named `max`.